# Is .Net and as .Net Core the same framework but with different names?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

As the .Net technology changes and improves the change is also evident in the .Net Frameworks.

[What's new in .Net 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five) gave a clear explanation about today's current framework improvement.

> .NET 5.0 is the next major release of .NET Core following 3.1. We named this new release .NET 5.0 instead of .NET Core 4.0 for two reasons:
>
> We skipped version numbers 4.x to avoid confusion with .NET Framework
> 4.x. We dropped "Core" from the name to emphasize that this is the main implementation of .NET going forward. .NET 5.0 supports more
> types of apps and more platforms than .NET Core or .NET Framework.

However, there is one thing I don't quite fully understand. After reading the above text, is it stating that the framework *.Net Core* is being renamed to *.Net* from here on out? Thus, *.Net Core* and *.Net* are the same framework but with different names?

Comment: As I said in the comment to your other question. Yes. Starting with now, there is the ".NET Framework" (which will never get past 4.something - unless Microsoft changes its mind) and ".NET" which is the follow-on to ".NET Core"

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes I read your comment. I posted this question before I found out about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw the names out, the answer is very clear,

- .NET Framework 1.0 -> .NET Framework 1.1 -> .NET Framework 2.0 -> ... -> .NET Framework 3.5 -> .NET Framework 4.0 -> ... -> .NET Framework 4.8 (no more release from here)
- .NET Core 1.0 -> .NET Core 1.1 -> .NET Core 2.0 -> ... -> .NET Core 3.1 -> .NET 5 -> .NET 6 -> ?

Comment: I noticed how you drew out the names in two seperate bullets points. In that case, while .Net Core and .Net are the same framework (.Net core renamed to .Net), the .Net Framework is a totally different framework from them?

Comment: Yes, .NET Framework was a Windows only framework, .NET Core was aimed at cross-platform.

Comment: .NET 5 is to .NET Core 3.x as .NET Core 3.x is to .NET Core 2.x .. (they are based on the same lineage, yet are different / separate versions). The “core” lineage is separate from the .NET Framework lineage.

Comment: @user2864740 technically no longer called the "core" lineage, since .Net Core is now  renamed to .Net

Comment: “core” lineage, quotes important ^_^